# WCF slow on every request

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I have a WCF service, which connects with SQL server and fetch some data, construct objects and then returns it. I use simple binding, .NET 4.0, I have not added any special setting just default settings from template when you create WCF service.

The service runs fine on my local with local db but now when I deployed on server, I checked the time, the processing takes 7 microseconds (first one takes little more) but before reaching the START to process, WCF is taking **3 seconds** on every request before hitting first line of code and I can't find why.

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="Local.IService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
```

Thanks!

Service behavior:

```
    <behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior>
<!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
<!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Bindings:

```
    <bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" />
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: What does you 'ServiceBehavior' attribute look like? Please post it.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the ServiceBehavior attribute on the class.

Comment: I don't have any ServiceBehavior attribute on the class

Comment: How are you hosting your WCF service, is it self hosted or on IIS? Also, have you profiled your DB lookup code?

Answer (score 0):

One of the main things that happens between when the request hits IIS and when it gets to your C# code is the security check. Depending on your set up you may not have any security on your dev machine.

Assuming that you are using Windows Authentication with NTLM. Then there is a 3 request handshake with a http , 401.2, 401.1 and 200 response. In between these requests you web server will communicate with your AD server.

You should be able to see if this is the problem by checking your IIS logs.